# Cannot execute a MySQL prepared statement when using the mysql crate; the parameter is not replaced

Tags: mysql, rust

I tried using [`prep_exec`](http://blackbeam.org/doc/mysql/struct.Conn.html#method.prep_exec) with the [`params!`](http://blackbeam.org/doc/mysql/macro.params!.html) macro like in the examples for [`Conn`](http://blackbeam.org/doc/mysql/struct.Conn.html), and also with `prepare` and then [`execute`](http://blackbeam.org/doc/mysql/struct.Stmt.html#method.execute) from [`Stmt`](http://blackbeam.org/doc/mysql/struct.Stmt.html).

This function works:

```
pub fn get(DB: Pool, name: &str) -> Option<Settings> {
    let mut ret: Option<Settings> = None;
    let mut stmt = DB.prepare("SELECT * FROM settings").unwrap();
    for row in stmt.execute().unwrap() {
        let mut row = row.unwrap();
        ret = Some(Settings {
            id: row.take("id").unwrap(),
            host: row.take("host"),
            name: row.take("name").unwrap(),
            value: row.take("value"),
        });
        break;
    }

    ret
}
```

But this does not work, the parameter is not replaced:

```
pub fn get(DB: Pool, name: &str) -> Option<Settings> {
    let mut ret: Option<Settings> = None;
    let mut stmt = DB.prepare("SELECT * FROM settings WHERE name=?").unwrap();
    for row in stmt.execute((name)).unwrap() {
        let mut row = row.unwrap();
        ret = Some(Settings {
            id: row.take("id").unwrap(),
            host: row.take("host"),
            name: row.take("name").unwrap(),
            value: row.take("value"),
        });
        break;
    }

    ret
}
```

The error is

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: MySqlError { ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' WHERE name=?' at line 1 }'

Comment: I am unsure exactly.. but [it looks to me like the source code](http://blackbeam.org/doc/src/mysql/src/value.rs.html#1041-1046) wants at least two tuple items. Can you try doing: `stmt.execute((name, ))` (note the extra comma).

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to write that code quite so imperatively; you can [treat it as an iterator](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=63dccde566d577619a97159902fda123&version=stable) (untested, but shows the right idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the [documentation you linked](http://blackbeam.org/doc/mysql/struct.Stmt.html#method.execute).

```
let mut stmt1 = pool.prepare("SELECT ?").unwrap();

// just do not forget about trailing comma in case of arity = 1
for row in stmt1.execute((42,)).unwrap() {
    let cell = from_row::<u8>(row.unwrap());
    assert_eq!(cell, 42u8);
}
```

Make sure that you have the trailing comma in `execute` if you have only one parameter.

Comment: Heh, I missed that. Probably easier to read the documentation than trawl through the macro definitions!

Comment: @SimonWhitehead assuming that documentation is good is a risky bet usually. At least the code won't lie to you (usually).